# Strings containing all possible n letter, k symbol substrings.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

Denote a perfect $[n,k]$ string as $Z_1Z_2Z_3...Z_{k^n+n-1}$ if each substring $Z_iZ_{i+1}Z_{i+2}...Z_{i+n-1}$ is unique. (There are $k^n$ possible substrings, so this question is asking for a string containing each of them exactly once)

Here's an example for 3 letters, 2 symbols (a perfect $[3,2]$ string): $aaababbbaa$. You can see that all 8 substrings $(aaa,aab,aba...bbb)$ are present.

Given that a perfect $[4,3]$ string starts off $caacb$, what are the possible combinations for the last 3 letters? 5 letters? Can you list all possible strings?

Bonus: A perfect $[4,4]$ string starts off $acdcabbabadcabdad$, find at least one string.

The bonus question might require code but I'd like to see a non-programming solution to the [4,3] enigma if possible.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence